# Is there a way to make the python-vlc window acknowledge cropping?

Tags: python, vlc, python-vlc

I want to play a video using `python-vlc`. I have gotten everything to work, and the video plays without any technical issues. There is this one aesthetic issue, though. I only want to play part of the video. As in, I want to crop out a fair bit on the bottom and a good bit on the right. I know I can do this with a call to `MediaPlayer.video_set_crop_geometry()`, and I've done so semi-successfully. However, the actual window that opens is the one that is adjusted for the entire video, with the part that I want centered in the middle with black bars around it. (If I call `MediaPlayer.video_set_scale()`, then the cropped-out bit the same size as it would be if I didn't crop. If I don't call `video_set_scale()`, the cropped-out bit is stretched, maintaining aspect ratio, until it reaches the edge of the window. Regardless, there are black bars).

Can I get the window to adjust to this new, smaller video? Preferably automatically, but if I have to pass in the size I want, that's fine too.

I have tried shuffling around the order between the different calls to no avail. Clearly `python-vlc` has the capacity somewhere to adjust the window it's playing in, as it can open a window the correct size for the regular video to play, and it adjusts automaticallty after calling `video_set_scale()`, but only to fit the original video, not the cropped one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably share more details, such as your full code and platform used.

That being said, libvlc doesn't offer an API to resize the native Window it draws on, but you can easily do it yourself (with win32 APIs for HWND, on Windows, for example).

Comment: `MediaPlayer.get_xwindow()` it is. Presumably I would need `python-xlib` to do anything with it. I'll look into it. At any rate, libvlc not exposing any resizing API is basically the answer I'm after, although not the one I wanted.

Comment: I guess resizing windows is not in the scope of libvlc :) However, the good news is libvlc will be listening for size changes of that window, and will adapt its video output accordingly, so you don't have to take care of this, at least.

Comment: That's a good thing, yes. Also, I think I'll just do the dirty thing and call `os.system("wmctrl -e")`. Messing with GTK or Xlib looks too convoluted.